# GPS Device is sending junk data

Tags: node.js, sockets, gps

I have a GPS device BW08C and when I configured with IP and protocol it is sending some raw junk on server. On other hand when I worked with other GPS device like LKGPS LK209 it gives me proper data on socket.io server.

```
root@server:/home/gpsdevice/nodejs-bw08# node example.js
Socket server is ready
Connected to Socket server
Sending GPS data string for processing
CTRL+C to exit
test
f��182D�
f��182DA�
xx
��
f��182D
�
xx

�/
���182D
xx
��
f��182D%�
xx
�
f��182DY
xx
NY
f��182D�
xx
^�
f��182DPu
xx
lC
f��182D ��
f��182D
       �/
xx
��
f��182Dʹ
xx
�
f��182D�
xx
&7
f��182Dro
xx
mK
f��182D��
xx
��
f��182D�
x
�
f��182D̼
^C
```

Please let me know what type of data is it and is my GPS device have issue or I am not understanding data encoding.

Comment: Could you show a hexdump/bytearray of the messages? Since it's not text, the screenshot is of little use (not to mention part of it is cut off).

Comment: I'm not sure but i think this might be off-topic

Comment: @garwity Edited the code.